# My Bloch sphere is appearing as an ellipse/oval

Tags: jupyter-notebook, quantum-computing, qiskit

I tried to plot a Bloch vector. However, my Bloch sphere is appearing as an ellipse/oval instead of a circle. I am having the same issues with qsphere also.[Jupyter notebook on my Mac(Safari)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juboj.png)

```
from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_vector

%matplotlib inline

plot_bloch_vector([0,1,0], title="New Bloch Sphere")
```

Comment: Did you try changing the aspect ratio with the `figsize` option?

Comment: Yes, I tried. However, it is only change the size of the figure not the shape.

Comment: Also, I thought it may be a problem with the jupyter notebook, so I executed the code in IBM Q Experience and still the problem was there.

Comment: An issue has been opened for this problem: github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/4770. It looks like it might be an issue with a specific matplotlib version

Comment: Thank You. I changed my version of Matplotlib from 3.3.0 to 3.2.2 and it solved the problem.